# Windows Print Spool Location Variable

Tags: python, windows, printing

My mom's printer acts strangely sometimes and screws up, won't print and then can't delete, stop, restart, or anything any documents in the spool.  I wrote a python program that stops the print spooler service, empties the spool folder, and then turns print spooler service back on.  Currently the location of the print spool folder is hard coded into the program.

My question is is there a system or environment variable that is common to the various flavors of windows that returns where the spool folder is at?  Or can that folder even be changed from the default such that I shouldn't even worry about it?

Comment: You oughta sell your program to HP :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the spool directory is specific to each printer (and it can be changed).  You can get it via [GetPrinterData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd144912.aspx) with SPLREG_DEFAULT_SPOOL_DIRECTORY.